# Getting unittest PySide and Maya on commandline to work

Tags: python, pyside, maya

I have a Maya environment with a PySide window which gets generated on the fly with whatever is in that Maya scene. I'm trying to now take that to command-line and make unittests out of it.

I have everything working, minus one problem. 
Most PyQt/PySide unittest documentation state to create a QApplication like this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = SomeWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This doesn't work because there's already a QApplication instance, built from Maya.

```
RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.
```

Excluding these steps though yields this error and the tests fail:

```
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used
```

I know that there's a QApplication instance in the scene, because this command yields a QApplication instance:

```
QApplication.instance()
```

So how do I associate the GUI that I want to create with that instance? You can't exec_() Maya's running QApplication so I'm not sure how to get my GUI to see the QApplication.
_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The issue was that I wasn't holding a global reference to the same instance across all of my tests (multiple Maya files were being created/destroyed over and over).

So somewhere at the top of the file, you just write

```
APP = None
```

Then in each test, import another file that keeps a link to that QApplication instance as a singleton and set APP equal to it